# How can I achieve this design in Flutter app with response coming from Laravel Api?

Tags: php, laravel, flutter, flutter-layout

I am trying to develop an app for schools and parents where the class teachers will be able to upload pictures of a student when a student check-in to school and check-out from school. This app will have a backend which will be built using laravel 9. The whole app is based on API.
[Image of App User Interface here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G1iya.jpg)

I want to show photos of check-in and check-out side by side based on the date. If check-out is not updated yet, then the check-in image will be there and the check-out section will be empty.

Here is the JSON response that I am working with:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "child_id": 1,
            "date": "18-08-2022",
            "time": "08:49:51",
            "status": "check_in",
            "image": "https://via.placeholder.com/640x480.png/008833?text=kids+et"
        },
        {
            "id": 6,
            "child_id": 1,
            "date": "18-08-2022",
            "time": "10:24:38",
            "status": "check_out",
            "image": "https://via.placeholder.com/640x480.png/00ffdd?text=kids+veritatis"
        }
    ]
}
```

Laravel Controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Api\V1;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Http\Requests\StoreCheckInOutRequest;
use App\Http\Requests\UpdateCheckInOutRequest;
use App\Http\Resources\V1\CheckInOut\CheckInOutResource;
use App\Models\CheckInOut;
use App\Services\V1\CheckInOutQuery;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class CheckInOutController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $filter = new CheckInOutQuery();
        $queryItems = $filter->transform($request); //[['column', 'operator', 'value']]

        if (count($queryItems) == 0) {
            return response()->json(['message' => 'No child id provided'], 400);
        } else {
            return CheckInOutResource::collection(CheckInOut::where($queryItems)->orderBy('date', 'desc')->get());

        }
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(StoreCheckInOutRequest $request)
    {
        $checkInOut = CheckInOut::create($request->all());

        return response()->json(['message' => 'Check in & out status created successfully.', 'data' => $checkInOut], 201);
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  \App\Models\CheckInOut  $checkInOut
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show(CheckInOut $checkInOut)
    {
        return new CheckInOutResource($checkInOut);
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \App\Models\CheckInOut  $checkInOut
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(UpdateCheckInOutRequest $request, CheckInOut $checkInOut)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  \App\Models\CheckInOut  $checkInOut
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy(CheckInOut $checkInOut)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

Laravel API Resource:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Resources\V1\CheckInOut;

use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\JsonResource;

class CheckInOutResource extends JsonResource
{
    /**
     * Transform the resource into an array.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array|\Illuminate\Contracts\Support\Arrayable|\JsonSerializable
     */
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'id' => $this->id,
            'child_id' => $this->child_id,
            'date' => date('d-m-Y', strtotime($this->date)),
            'time' => $this->time,
            'status' => $this->status,
            'image' => $this->image
        ];
    }
}
```

Database Migration:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

return new class extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('check_in_outs', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('child_id');
            $table->date('date');
            $table->time('time');
            $table->string('status')->comment('check_in, check_out');
            $table->string('image')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('check_in_outs');
    }
};
```

CheckInOut Model:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class CheckInOut extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = [
        'child_id',
        'date',
        'time',
        'status',
        'image'
    ];

    protected $hidden = [
        'created_at',
        'updated_at'
    ];

    public function child()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Child::class);
    }
}
```

Please help me, how can I design my API response and handle the API response to achieve my goal of design in flutter? [Image of App User Interface here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G1iya.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

The backend information is irrelevant, we only have to take into account the response in json

1. Create a model of your response. (You can use https://quicktype.io/ and paste your json output to get the Model class in Dart, the class you will get already has methods to map the objects from json.)
2. The design is not difficult, you should visit https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/widgets/material.

API requests can be done with https://pub.dev/packages/http and you can show images with https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/images/network-image
. Hope it helps your asking for a lot of information.

Comment: thank you for providing an answer ... this site is an English only site, please translate any non-English text into English, thank you

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. Actually, It's my bad that I asked the question in the wrong way. The mentioned UI design is done by me. I need a solution to achieve the functionality that I mention above (programmatical solution).